Determiners & pronouns in "One of the students is intelligent. Some of them were British."


One of the students is intelligent.
Some of them were British.


What I think is one & some are pronouns and of the students & of them are modifiers of the head one & some.
But why are one of & some of considered determiners?

@JamesMathai distributors are for cars. It's distributive.

They are neither pronouns nor determiners. "One of the students" and "some of them" are noun phrases.
"One" can be a pronoun or determiner. For example, in the sentence "I have two students, and one is clever", it represents the noun "one student". But when it is modified with the prepositional phrase 'of the' it is not a pronoun but a quantifier counting the number within the group (the students). It can also be used as an ordinal number and of course a cardinal number as a determiner.
"Some" can also be a pronoun or determiner, but the same is true as with 'one' - when you modify it to become a noun phrase it cannot stand on its own as either. "Some of the students" could not be replaced by "some students" without context, that could mean all students everywhere in general. "Some of the students" can only refer to some of a group you mention or have already mentioned. You could say "some students in the class" but that is another noun phrase.

I've read my answer back a few times thinking of how I can possibly make it clearer, but it's difficult to explain why something isn't something else. It's like explaining why a balloon isn't a brick. There aren't any peer-reviewed studies on the differences between bricks and balloons. Hopefully you can see that the functions are different. Of these phrases and pronouns/determiners, I mean. Not bricks and balloons.

Although to be fair the functions of bricks and balloons also differ.

I see no difference meaning between "some of the boys in the class are nice" and "some boys in the class are nice". The difference is in the grammar, which you rightly point out, and not in the meaning. Why is that a problem?

OP's Query:
Why are "one of" and "some of" considered determiners and not pronouns in these sentences?


One of the students is intelligent.
Some of them were British.


Answer:
In modern grammar, "one of" and  "some of" are considered  determiners because they function as units that introduce, specify, or quantify a noun or pronoun.

*"One of the students"*→ specifies exactly one member of the group "the students."
*"Some of them"*→ identifies an unspecified subset of "them."

Why Determiners (Modern View):.
Determiners modify nouns or pronouns and indicate quantity, specificity, or possession. Here,  "one of" and  "some of" specify subsets within a group. The "of" construction links the determiner to the group being referred to (e.g., the students, them).
Cambridge Grammar Reference::.
Determiners with of.
Expressions like  "one of," "some of," and similar constructions are treated as determiners when followed by "of" plus articles, demonstratives, or possessives. For example:
Most of her friends got married before she did.
Two of my favorite books are missing
This modern interpretation aligns with their role in specifying or quantifying nouns.
Edit - 1.
As OP pointed out:
Traditional grammar treats "one" and "some" as pronouns, with "of the students" and "of them" as modifiers.
However, grammar evolves, and in modern grammar, these constructions are now considered determiners because they function as units that specify or quantify a noun or pronoun.
